# Does the Amazon cloudfront domain name ever change?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I've setup a cloudfront distribution pointing to my EC2 instance (web server), tucked inside a ELB.

I'm an unsure if this cloudfront domain name will ever change? (I.E when enabling/disabling it, attaching/reattaching etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So long as the distribution still exists, it will use the same domain on cloudfront (the one assigned to you at the distribution's creation time). [This cloudfront domain will only be lost when a distribution is deleted:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-cleanup-cloudfront.html)

> A disabled distribution is no longer functional and you will no longer
>   be charged, but it can be enabled again at any time. A deleted
>   distribution is no longer accessible and is lost forever.

If you want to preserve the assigned cloudfront domain but temporarily disable access to it, use the AWS console to disable it - not delete it.

The only reason I've had to delete distributions is for general cleanup of old ones, or when I've been close to their limit of 100 distributions per account (which has only happened once to me).

For even greater control, you also have the option of [mapping your own domain name to a distribution using a CNAME record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html):

> In CloudFront, an alternate domain name, also known as a CNAME, lets
>   you use your own domain name (for example, www.example.com) for links
>   to your objects instead of using the domain name that CloudFront
>   assigns to your distribution.

The above is the approach I use because I like more control over resources, but depending on your use case it might be overkill since the original distribution name won't change unless you delete it.

Comment: Thanks! I have a side question, I'm confused on how the actual system works. I have hosted my files on EC2. When a request to the CF resource is made, does Amazon check if the file exists on their server, if it doesn't do they pull it from mine, then cache on theres?

Comment: When you request an object from CF, you are connecting to one of its edge servers (of which they have many). This edge server checks to see if it has a cached copy of your requested object, and if not, retrieves the original object from your distribution source (in your case EC2). Objects on cloudfront have an expiry time, after which they will be retrieved again on the next request from the original server. If you need more details, please lookup their documentation or read in general about Content Distribution Networks.

Comment: Also a word of caution: Not understanding very specificallt how an AWS service operates can often result in surprise charges to your account. It's probably happened to every single AWS user at least once, which is part of why they have those free usage tiers.